# Javascript join two json and compare

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, while-loop

I have this code:

```
var json = '[{"id":113,"price":55,"start":"Sun, 24 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"title":"","start":"2016-04-25T23:00:00.000Z","price":"115.7"},{"title":"","start":"2016-05-06T23:00:00.000Z","price":"115.7"},{"id":114,"price":45,"start":"Sun, 08 May 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":9},{"title":"","start":"2016-05-08T23:00:00.000Z","price":"115.7"},{"id":111,"price":55,"start":"Wed, 01 Jun 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":11},{"title":"","start":"2016-06-01T23:00:00.000Z","price":"115.7"},{"id":110,"price":53,"start":"Fri, 03 Jun 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8}]';

moment.utc().valueOf(); 

function fulljson(data) {

  data = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 

  start = moment.utc('Sun, 24 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000').valueOf()/86400000; 
  start = parseInt(start);
  console.log('pocetak'+start);

  now = moment.utc().valueOf()/86400000;
  now = parseInt(now); 
  console.log('sada'+now);

  end = moment.utc('Sun, 05 Jun 2016 00:00:00 +0000').valueOf()/86400000; 
  end = parseInt(end);
  console.log('kraj'+end);

  auction_end = parseInt('3');
  now = now + auction_end;
  console.log('a sada je '+now);

  if (start > now) {
    pocetak = start;
    console.log(pocetak);
  } else {
    pocetak = now;
    console.log(pocetak);
  }

var array_of_all_dates = [];
  for (i = pocetak; i < end; i++) { 
    var new_object = {
                    title: '1',
                    start: moment(i*86400000).utcOffset('+0000').format(),
                    price: '{{$article->lowest_bid}}'
                };
    array_of_all_dates.push(new_object);
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(array_of_all_dates));
  console.log(array_of_all_dates);
};


fulljson(json);
```

so at the end you see that I have `json` and `array_of_all_dates`. Now I want to **join** `json` to `array_of_all_dates` but if the same `start` element already excist into `array_of_all_dates` then remove it from array_of_all_dates and put this from `json`...

http://jsbin.com/qekijumobe/edit?html,js,output

How to do this? please help.

Comment: Just to be certain I know what you are asking. You are attempting to **join** the arrays on the **start** property. When you find a matched object you want to replace that object in the `array_of_all_dates` array with the corresponding object from the `json` array.

Is that correct?

Comment: yes,and also you can use day from array_of_all_dates is the same as moment.utc(json.start).valueOf()/86400000; from json ... so you can compare that two values

Comment: but also you can use start from both ... to compare

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand and interpret your question

Json is

```
[  
   {  
      "id":113,
      "price":55,
      "start":"Sun, 24 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000",
      "user_id":8
   },
   {  
      "title":"",
      "start":"2016-04-25T23:00:00.000Z",
      "price":"115.7"
   },
   {  
      "title":"",
      "start":"2016-05-06T23:00:00.000Z",
      "price":"115.7"
   },
..
}
```

And array_of_all_dates is

```
[  
   {  
      "title":"1",
      "start":"2016-04-24T00:00:00+00:00",
      "day":16915,
      "price":100
   },
   {  
      "title":"1",
      "start":"2016-04-25T00:00:00+00:00",
      "day":16916,
      "price":100
   },
   {  
      "title":"1",
      "start":"2016-04-26T00:00:00+00:00",
      "day":16917,
      "price":100
   },
...
}
```

So you need to join these two, without having a duplicate "start" field.
My approach would be too merge the two JSON dataobjects, and remove the duplicate start field items.

Sample Implementation in JQuery:

Lets say you append both the lists into one list called mergedItems then

```
var uniqueItems = [];
$.each(mergedItems["start"], function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueItems ) === -1) uniqueItems.push(el);
});
```

Edit:
Working Example

http://jsbin.com/vakodahile/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Can you please add this here: http://jsbin.com/qekijumobe/edit?html,js,output ... there is both

Comment: @Andrew. I've updated a working copy.  If you need start from json, then do json.concat(array)

Comment: hm, k, nice, but I dont see full json, just start

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy javascript library http://underscorejs.org/ that you can use for this. It's not exactly join, but it accomplishes the task with a single loop.

```
  _.each(jQuery.parseJSON(json), function(d){    

      console.log(d.start)  
      var idx = _.findIndex(array_of_all_dates, function(ad){ return d.start == ad.start });

      if(idx>-1){
          array_of_all_dates[idx] = d;
      }
  });
```

I did notice there there were no matches because your date formats don't match exactly. You can try instantiating a new moment object in the `findIndex` predicate and specify a specific datetime format.